# how can i show only max rows grouped by id in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I want to show only the biggest value from my table GROUPED BY NAME

I have the table:

```
ID   name  money
1    jim   100
2    aura  150
3    mike  200
4    jim   300
5    aura  450
6    mike  1000
```

mysql query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```

and result are only first 3 id and i want to show only the biggest value in money: id 4, 5 and 6

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use aggregate function `MAX`:

```
SELECT name, MAX(money) FROM table GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use belowquery,might be you get your solution.
SELECT name,max([money]) as MaxSalary
FROM table
GROUP BY name